# Angular Server Side Rendering - What to add to angular.json?

Tags: html, json, angular, firebase

I'm following [Firebase's Tutorial for SSR with Angular](https://youtu.be/gxCu5TEmxXE?t=382). Unfortunately the Tutorial is outdated, since as for Angular 6 `angular-cli.json` was replaced with `angular.json`. How do I translate the step, you can find by using the link, to the `angular.json` file?

For comparison, here's what my file looks like:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "norebro": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/norebro",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            ...
```

Comment: For Angular 8 you can see the instructions [here](https://angular.io/guide/universal) (btw, it's waaay simpler to setup SSR with Angular 8)... As for Angular 6, you can find the official documentation [here](https://v6.angular.io/guide/universal), you have everything you need to setup SSR there...

Comment: @miselking Thanks, I'm using Angular 8. Do you happen to know any tutorial how to use Angular 8 SSR with Firebase? I'm pretty new to the topic.

Comment: I know that you can't deploy an Angular Universal app to a static host (i.e. Firebase Hosting, AWS S3,...). But, you can use `Firebase Cloud Functions`. I added an answer with this approach although I didn't test it... Hopefully it will work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, since you are using Angular 8 you can run this command to make your project use SSR:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject norebro
```

After you run this command you should get everything setup properly by Angular for you. To check if everything is working first build your project:

```
npm run build:ssr
```

and then serve it (and check if everything is working correctly):

```
npm run serve:ssr
```

Specifically, the things that need to be modified inside `angular.json`are:

- In "projects"->"norebro" (*your_project_name*)->"architect"->"build"->"options" section modify `outputPath` like this:

```
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          "outputPath": "dist/browser",
```

- Then in "architect" section, add a new `server` section like this:

```
    "server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "sourceMap": false,
          "optimization": {
            "scripts": false,
            "styles": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

---

As for publishing an Angular SSR application to Firebase please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447458/deploy-angular-8-universal-ssr-application-on-firebase/58447459#58447459) answer.

The key point is that we cannot deploy Angular SSR application using Firebase Hosting but we can do it by using *[Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)*.

**P.S:** Initially, the answer was posted here but users may not find the answer to Firebase deployment here when querying (since the OP is not about deployment to Firebase). That's why I created a separate Q&A just to address that issue.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Immediately under `build`(but not inside) you should add the configuration for your server application. It would look something like this:

```
"server": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                "options": {
                    "outputPath": "dist/server",
                    "main": "src/main.server.ts",
                    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
                    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                        "includePaths": [
                            "src/styles"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                        "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputHashing": "media"
                    },
                    "dev": {
                        "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
```

Note that this one has some irrelevant properties, such as `stylePreprocessorOptions`. Let's focus on those relevant, which are the **`builder`**, **`outputPath`**, **`main`**, and **`tsConfig`**. Those are the files that would potentially change between a Server Side Rendered application and a Client Side Rendered application.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggled with many tutorials while I was building a project with Angular Universal, the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/universal/getting-started.md) of AngularFire2 was really straightforward.